# How to best analyze and understand the .sln file I've been given?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

I've been handed off a rather complex web app from a prior developer with whom I have no way of communicating going forward.  My experience in development is still beginner, and I need to determine the best way to wrap my head around what is going on with this app.

I've been given the full .sln file.  I am very comfortable with the basics of navigating Visual Studio.  I was trained in C#, but this app contains several additional components that I'm still learning (js extensions, cshtml files). I know the answer is to learn what I don't know, but I'm under a tight time constraint for my employer.  What I mainly want to be able to do to start is be able to get to the underlying code of any given functionality within the UI of the web app, e.g. there is a button called "Perform a Test Run" - as simple as it should be to navigate to the underlying code that is run when that button is clicked, I can not seem to locate it.  It's certainly not where I expect it to be for the way I was taught.

I tried an app called NDepend to run an analysis but that wasn't helpful to me, unfortunately.

Can anyone suggest a tool or an approach for me to start understanding how this all works together?  There are almost no developer comments within any of the code.

I don't know if this helpful, but here is a screenshot of the top-level of the solution to see what different kinds of components are included. The 2nd image is the Scripts folder expanded.

[image: Solution Explorer Screenshot]

[image: Scripts Folder Expanded]

Comment: How familiar are you with (Microsoft) [MVC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASP.NET_MVC)?

Comment: What version of Visual Studio are you using?

Comment: I am very familiar with the overall MVC concept in programming and UI's.  I use VS Community 2015.

Comment: right click button. Inspect element. copy something unique about the element such as the class. CTRL + SHIFT + F to do a solution-wide search and then search for where all instances of that class are used.

Comment: GETs and POSTs - ie, button clicks and the like - typically wind up executing a controller action (method), possible after some JavaScript. Look at the classes in your Controllers folder. The route (URL) you use to get to a page determines which controller class will handle the request. MVC is very different than webforms or winforms development. I'd suggest taking an hour to go through Microsoft's ASP.NET MVC tutorials.

Comment: David Lively and Martin Dawson, very good, thank you kindly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution is for an ASP.NET MVC project.  The files you are not familiar with (.js, .cshtml) are very common and frequently used file extensions for MVC projects.

".js" files are Javascript files

".cshtml" files are files that are html and/or Razor syntax.

The good news is, ASP.NET MVC is one of the best ways of making web applications currently, and learning it is fairly straight forward and not too daunting.  Especially if you say you have familiarity with the concept of MVC.

I will direct you to a few key resources:

[This is Microsoft's MVC portal with tutorials and documentation](https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview)
[This is a great Pluralsight course on some MVC5 fundamentals](https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/aspdotnet-mvc5-fundamentals)

Comment: This is very helpful.  Best to you, maccettura!